ElasticSearch BM25 retriever returns empty "id" field
I'm using the ElasticSearchBM25Retriever library on elasticsearch database to search for relevant documents, but the ElasticSearchBM25Retriever when called "invoke" returns only "page_content" of the results (Documents), leaving the "type", "id" and metadata tags as None.
I wrote the id when indexing the document, but it was ignored.
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

from langchain_community.retrievers import ElasticSearchBM25Retriever
from haystack_integrations.document_stores.elasticsearch import ElasticsearchDocumentStore
from haystack import Document
 

client = Elasticsearch([{'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 9200, 'scheme': 'http'}], verify_certs=False, timeout=15)

retriever = ElasticSearchBM25Retriever(index_name="default", client=client)

retriever.create("http://127.0.0.1:9200", "default")

data = [Document(content="hello world", id=0)] # <-- Where I placed the id.

ElasticsearchDocumentStore(hosts="http://127.0.0.1:9200/", index="default").write_documents(documents=data)

for token in retriever.invoke("world"):
    for data in token:
        print(data)


It returns:
('type', 'Document')
('id', None)
('metadata', {})
('page_content', 'Hello World')

